# Text search across multiple MS Word documents

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I apologize for such a basic and messy question... but this is my first attempt at PS scripting. I have a couple thousand Word documents in a C:\ directory that I need to query specific words/fields/bookmarks and export to  a .csv file. Or would VBA be better?

I've got this so PS script so far, but it only produces the first result in a single test document. I'll bake virtual cookies for anyone with advice!

```
#ERROR REPORTING ALL
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$path     = "C:\Users\PS Test"
$files    = Get-Childitem $path -Include *.docx,*.doc -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.psiscontainer) }
$output   = "C:\Users\PS Test\report.csv"
$application = New-Object -comobject word.application
$application.visible = $False
$findtext = "TEST1"
$charactersAround = 30
$results = @{}

Function getStringMatch
{
    # Loop through all *.doc files in the $path directory
    Foreach ($file In $files)
    {
        $document = $application.documents.open($file.FullName,$false,$true)
        $range = $document.content

        If($range.Text -match ".{$($charactersAround)}$($findtext).{$($charactersAround)}"){
             $properties = @{
                File = $file.FullName
                Match = $findtext
                TextAround = $Matches[0] 
             }
             $results += New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $properties
        }
    }

    If($results){
        $results | Export-Csv $output -NoTypeInformation
    }

    $document.close()
    $application.quit()
}

getStringMatch

import-csv $output
```

Comment: Change `$results = @{}` to `$results = @()` and move `$document.Close()` into the file loop (at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Plz Try this first:

This will output all of them not `only produces the first result in a single test document.`

### Using Find object method

```
#ERROR REPORTING ALL
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$path     = "X:\PS Test"
$files    = Get-Childitem $path -Include *.docx,*.doc -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.psiscontainer) }
$output   = "X:\PS Test\report.csv"
$application = New-Object -comobject word.application
$application.visible = $False
$findtext = "TEST1"
$charactersAround = 30
$results = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]

Function getStringMatch
{
    # Loop through all *.doc files in the $path directory
    Foreach ($file In $files)
    {
        $document = $application.documents.open($file.FullName,$false,$true)
        $range = $document.content

        while($range.find.execute($findtext)){
            $start = $range.start - $charactersAround
            if($start -lt 0){$start = 0}
            $end = $range.end + $charactersAround
            if($end -gt $document.content.end){$end = $document.content.end}
            $textAround = $document.range($start, $end).text

            $properties = @{
                File = $file.FullName
                Match = $findtext
                TextAround = $textAround 
             }
             $results.Add((New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $properties))

             # Move the start of the range to the end of the last match
             #$range.SetRange($range.end, $document.content.end)
        }
        $document.close()
    }

    If($results){
        $results | Export-Csv $output -NoTypeInformation
    }

    $application.quit()
}

getStringMatch

import-csv $output
```

Cause this `TextAround = $Matches[0]`, only the first result will be stored.

### Using RegExp

#### Neighboring matches are output as the same result

```
$path     = "X:\PS Test"
$files    = Get-Childitem $path -Include *.docx,*.doc -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.psiscontainer) }
$output   = "X:\PS Test\report.csv"
$findtext = "TEST1"
$charactersAround = 30
$results = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]

Function getStringMatch
{
    # Loop through all *.doc files in the $path directory
    Foreach ($file In $files)
    {
        # Convert the Word document to plain text
        $document = New-Object -ComObject word.application
        $document.visible = $false
        $doc = $document.documents.open($file.FullName)
        $txtFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file.FullName, ".txt")
        $doc.saveas([ref] $txtFile, [ref] 2)
        $doc.close()
        $document.quit()

        # Search the plain text file for matches
        $content = Get-Content -Path $txtFile -Raw
        
        # $regex = [regex]::new("(?s).{0,$($charactersAround)}$($findtext).{0,$($charactersAround)}")

        # [regex]::Matches($content, ".{$charactersAround}$findtext.{$charactersAround}") | ForEach-Object {
        [regex]::Matches($content, "(?s).{0,$($charactersAround)}$($findtext).{0,$($charactersAround)}") | ForEach-Object {
            $properties = @{
                File = $file.FullName
                Match = $findtext
                TextAround = $_.Value 
             }
             $results.Add((New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $properties))
        }

        # Delete the plain text file
        Remove-Item -Path $txtFile
    }

    If($results){
        $results | Export-Csv $output -NoTypeInformation
    }
}

getStringMatch

import-csv $output
```

#### Neighboring matching results are output as separate, independent results

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$path = "X:\PS Test"
$files = Get-Childitem $path -Include *.docx,*.doc -Recurse | Where-Object {
    !($_.psiscontainer)
}
$output = "X:\PS Test\report.csv"
$application = New-Object -comobject word.application
$application.visible = $False
$findtext = "TEST1"
$charactersAround = 30
$results = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]

Function getStringMatch {
    # Loop through all *.doc files in the $path directory
    Foreach ($file In $files) {
        $document = $application.documents.open($file.FullName,$false,$true)
        $range = $document.content

        <# if($range.Text -match ".{$($charactersAround)}$($findtext).{$($charactersAround)}"){        
             #for($i = 0 - $Matches.Count){
             for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Matches.Count; $i++){
             #for ($i = 0; $i -lt 13; $i++){
                 $properties = @{
                    File = $file.FullName
                    Match = $findtext
                    TextAround = $Matches[$i] 
                 }
                 $results.Add((New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $properties))
             }
        } #>
        
        #$regex = [regex]::new(".{$($charactersAround)}$($findtext).{$($charactersAround)}")
        # $regex = [regex]::new(".{$($charactersAround)}$($findtext).{$($charactersAround)}", 'Singleline')
        # $regex = [regex]::new(".{$($charactersAround)}$($findtext).{$($charactersAround)}", 'Multiline')
        
        # $escapedFindText = [regex]::Escape($findtext)
        # $regex = [regex]::new(".{$($charactersAround)}$($escapedFindText).{$($charactersAround)}")

        # $regex = [regex]::new("(?s).{$($charactersAround)}$($findtext).{$($charactersAround)}")

        # $regex = [regex]::new("(?s).{0,$($charactersAround)}$($findtext).{0,$($charactersAround)}")

        #$regex = [regex]::new("(?s)(?<=.{0,$($charactersAround)})$($findtext)(?=.{$($charactersAround)})")
        $regex = [regex]::new("(?s)(?<=.{0,$($charactersAround)})$($findtext)(?=.{0,$($charactersAround)})")


        # $text = $range.Text -replace "`r`n", " "
        # $matches = $regex.Matches($text)
        

           $text=$range.Text
          $matches = $regex.Matches($range.Text)
        if ($matches.Count -gt 0) {
        <#    foreach ($match in $matches) {
                $properties = @{
                    File = $file.FullName
                    Match = $findtext
                    TextAround = $match.Value
                }
                $results.Add((New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $properties))
            }
            #>
        

            <# $lastIndex = -1
            foreach ($match in $matches) {
                if ($lastIndex -lt 0 -or $match.Index - $lastIndex -ge $charactersAround * 2 + $findtext.Length) {
                # if ($lastIndex -lt 0 -or ($match.Index - $lastIndex -le $charactersAround -and $lastIndex -gt 0) -or $match.Index - $lastIndex -ge $charactersAround * 2 + $findtext.Length ) {
                    $properties = @{
                        File = $file.FullName
                        Match = $findtext
                        TextAround = $match.Value
                    }
                    $results.Add((New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $properties))
                }
                $lastIndex = $match.Index
            } #>
            
            
            foreach ($match in $matches) {
                $start = [Math]::Max(0, $match.Index - $charactersAround)
                $end = [Math]::Min($text.Length, $match.Index + $match.Length + $charactersAround)
                $textAround = $text.Substring($start, $end - $start)
                $properties = @{
                    File = $file.FullName
                    Match = $findtext
                    TextAround = $textAround
                }
                $results.Add((New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property $properties))
            }


        } 
        
        
        $document.close()
    }

    if($results.count -eq 0) {
        "No matches found."
        return
    }

    $results | Export-Csv $output -NoTypeInformation

    $application.quit()
}

getStringMatch

import-csv $output
```

Comment: Awesome, I will test those out and report back. Thank you!

Comment: Side question: would sql server mgmt studio be a better option?

Comment: @Bethany Hope this will solve your problem and close this question by accepting this. I have no idea why the SQL server mgmt studio is related to your question.